# Use Json array to populate chart

Tags: c#, javascript, highcharts

I am using [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to graph Json data.

I am using the line graph option whereby I am populating the points like so -

**C#**

```
protected string intsAsJSArray
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", listOfInts));
        }
    }
protected string datesAsJSArray
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", listOfDates));
        }
    }
```

**Aspx**

```
series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Count:',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 10, 31),
            data: <%= intsAsJSArray %>               
        }]
```

Currently the `pointStart` is hard coded, however what I want to achieve is for each date in `listOfDates` set a point on the graph for the corresponding int in `listOfInts`. I thought perhaps it would be a btter idea to return ONE list where each row is a join of an int and date i.e. `listOfRecords.Add(1,2013-10-31)` and then split this in the Javascript. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the x-axis variables equal to your list.

```
        var mydata = @Json.Encode(Model.intsAsJSArray);
        var myHeaders = @Html.Raw(@Json.Encode(Model.datesAsJSArray));

        $(function () {
            $('#chart').highcharts({
                xAxis: {
                    categories: myHeaders,
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Some data I have',
                    data: mydata
                }]
            });
        });
```

You'll have to make sure both arrays have equal size though. You can fill up an array with dates in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Other soultion is use x/y paramters for each point, use highstock and set ordinal parameter as false.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal